# How to get back order status of a product in Magento CE 1.7?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

How to get the `selected option value of backorders` in admin panel to `app/design/frontend/default/home/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml`. I have used the following code,but `$stockStatus` is null. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); 
$productData = $_product->getData();

$stockStatus = $productData['backorders'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$inventory =  Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$inventory->getBackorders();
```

will give you backorder stock status .

Comment: Can Grouped products use backorders?

Comment: No , grouped product rely on simple product

Comment: I have created a grouped product in backend. But there is no any place there to enable backorders for the product. I have changed the Availability message in frontend for simple products and enabled the Add to cart button as well. How can I do the same thing for grouped products?